# Wordpress. How to give parent page to a page create dinamiccaly in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a little script to create dinamically a page if this not exist, but I've a problem.
I want to give a parent page to the page that I going to create.

In few words something like:

if the page is created give it a Parent Page.

The Output that i want is:

http://exemple.com/ParentPage/ChildPage

and in the backend show automatically the Parent Page in the Page attributes instead of "(no parent)"

```
function check_pages_live(){
    if(get_page_by_title('Page Title') == NULL ) {
        create_pages_fly('Page Title');
    }

}
add_action('init','check_pages_live');

function create_pages_fly($pageName) {

    $parentPost = get_post( 2167 );

    $createPage = array(

      'post_title'    => $pageName,
      'post_content'  => 'Some Content',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     => 'page',
      'post_parent'   => $parentPost,
      'post_name'     => $pageName
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $createPage );
}
```

I've tried to create a class with get_post and the ID of the Parent Page; I've added that to the function, but nothing work.

Someone can help me please?

Thank a lot

Comment: the docs is the key to your answer: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) , 'post_parent' should be an integer. Setting it to  'post_parent'   => 2167 should do the trick.

Comment: I'll try to set 'post_parent' => 2167, but seems not do the trick.

Comment: What is the result of wp_insert_post( $createPage, true ); ? It should return an error message which should help debug the issue further.

Comment: thanks a lot for help. I fix the scritp; instead of wp_create_post( $createPage ); i try wp_insert_post($createPage); and it works